# Abscissa of a point of infinite order in an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

[image]

Any hints on this? I am fine with having a proof only for the case $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$ (if necessary, assume also $a_4 = 0$). I know how to work with the group law in general, but have no ideas apart from tackling an expression for $x([m]P)$ which will be too nasty, though.

Comment: You may find [division polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_polynomials) will help here.